# Accessing two different tables for one loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a small issue that I can't figure out.

I have to pull data from two different tables, in one loop. I've never done that before, so I have no idea how. I tried two different queries. That looked like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM colors ";
$color_select = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$second_query = "SELECT * FROM votes";
$vote_select = mysqli_query($connection, $second_query);
```

And then put them into a loop:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_select) && $second_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vote_select))
{
 $color = $row['Colors'];
 $votes = $second_row['Votes'];
 echo "<tr><td>$color</td><td>$votes</td></tr>";
}
```

But that didn't work. I didn't expect it to, just wanted to try. :) Maybe someone experienced can help me out. Thanks.

At the end of the day I need a table displayed, that has two columns, one of them contains the color name from one DB table and the other one contains a number of votes.

As requested: table structures.

Table: colors has only one field **Colors**.

Table: votes has four fields **city_id**, **City**, **Colors** and **Votes**

*************************EDIT**************************************
So fixed up the query as suggested, but is still shows nothing.

Here is the edited code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM colors,votes WHERE colors.Colors=votes.Colors"; 
$color_votes_select = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_votes_select))
{ $color = $row['Colors']; 
  $votes = $row['Votes']; }
```

Comment: How these 2 tables are related ?

Comment: if `color` table has a relation to `votes` use join

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty They are in the same Database

Comment: Is there any relation between two table?

Comment: I meant is there a common key between these 2 tables so that you know in the `votes`  table which vote is for which color ?

Comment: @TacoCat: edit your question and add table structures to it.

Comment: @RAvinderReddy Added, I hope I did it right. :) I'm just learning

Comment: SELECT
  `Colors`.*,votes.*
FROM
  `Colors`
INNER JOIN
  `votes` ON
  `votes`.Colors = `Colors`.Colors

Comment: @Pankajkatiyar when I try to echo the results, if gives me nothing, no errors, no echos.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM colors,votes where colors.Colors=votes.Colors";
    $color_votes_select = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_votes_select))
    {

         $color = $row['Colors'];
         $votes = $row['Votes'];
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if table having relation.

try this in single query .

```
SELECT
  `colors`.*,votes.*
FROM
  `colors`
INNER JOIN
  `votes` ON
  `votes`.colorId = `colors`.Id
```

Comment: Ok, but how does the while loop changes in that case?

Comment: your result will produce in single query

Answer (score 0):

Most imp *****You should have some relationship between tables

Otherwise workaround

1. Run query on color, Save it in ArrayA
2. Run query on vote, Save it in ArrayB
3. Create New Array ArrayC

   $arrayC = array();
   Loop array A or C if they both contact same row count
   array_push($ArrayC, key and value of color, key and value of votes);
4. Final loop ArrayC to print tr and td

Answer (score 0):

First Relate These two tables, write color_id in votes table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM colors,votes where colors.id=votes.color_id";

$color_select = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_select))
```

{

```
 $color = $row['Colors'];
 $votes = $row['Votes'];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT colors FROM colors"; 
$color_select = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

$second_query = "SELECT votes FROM votes"; //you only need column votes right?
$vote_select = mysqli_query($connection, $second_query) or die (mysqli_error());;

 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_select) && $second_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($vote_select)){

  $color[] = $row['colors'];
 $votes[] = $second_row['votes'];
 echo "<tr><td>$color</td><td>$votes</td></tr>";
 }
```

Short explanation:
It will fetch the select and store into an array (because what you were doing is selecting multiple rows into one single variable) and then just display with the echo.

Comment: I'm not trying to store the values into variables. If that was the case, your example would have helped. 

I just need to echo them. :)

Comment: Did you tried? Because it's better to have them all for later being used (echo in this case). Is not working then?
Btw, it's supposed to display all the colors and votes of each column regardless if they are related or not. That can be change with the query tho.